# How to create an alert (not notification)when the app is closed on Swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am working on my first project with SwiftUI using Xcode 11 and I can't seem to find a way to use an `Alert` that prompts the user with buttons.

[image]

I basically want to trigger an alert when the user leaves the set area when the app is closed (user closes the app by removing it from the stack) and the user can either press "yes" or a "no".

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can only use Alerts while your app is in the foreground, and you can use Local Notifications when your app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Full screen alerts like the one in your screenshot cannot be shown when your app is not in the foreground. For your use case, your best bet is to look into actionable notifications. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types